# Python check if next in array is the same

Tags: python

I'm making a python script to roll dices. I got everything working except for one bit. When someone rolls 4, 4 times in a row, it should roll another 4 dices.
I basically want to check if the next four numbers in an array are the same as the previous ones, to check for a "combo".

For example:

[4, 4, 4, 4] equals true and 4 more random integers are added to array

[4, 3, 1, 4] equals false.

Does anyone know I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show the part of the code that you are having a hard time with. Provide a sample input and explicit exact output and explain what difficulties you are facing in your current code.

Comment: Why not just store the last 4 rolls?

Comment: Yeah, sorry I'm very new to asking questions here, will do in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the piece you're missing is the **all** function, applied to a comprehension.  Something like

```
if all([rolls[i+n] == rolls[i] for n in range(4)]):
    # Perform 4 more rolls
```

The comprehension (for loop inside a list expression) generates four boolean results; **all** decides whether all of the elements are **True**.  FYI, the "or" version of **all** is the **any** function.

Answer (score 0):

You could just extract the last 4 rolls, convert them to a set and see if there's only one element in this.

You'd also need to make sure there have been at least 4 rolls, to not return `True` for `[4,4]` for example :

```
def test_last_four(rolls):
    if len(rolls) >= 4 and len(set(rolls[-4:])) == 1:
        return rolls[-1]

print(test_last_four([1, 4, 4, 4, 4]))
#=> 4
print(test_last_four([1, 4, 3, 1, 4]))
#=> None
print(test_last_four([4, 4]))
#=> None
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def checkForBeingTheSame(listOfRoles):
    if listOfRoles[-1]==listOfRoles[-2]:
        if listOfRoles[-2]==listOfRoles[-3]:
            if listOfRoles[-3]==listOfRoles[-4]:
                return True
    return False
```

Are you looking something like this?(top)
You can also add 4 more random digits like this.(bottem)

```
def checkForBeingTheSame():
    global listOfRoles
    if listOfRoles[-1]==listOfRoles[-2]:
        if listOfRoles[-2]==listOfRoles[-3]:
            if listOfRoles[-3]==listOfRoles[-4]:
                for i in range(4):
                    listOfRoles.append(randint(1,6))
                return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1, 2, 4, 4]
print a.count(4) == len(a)

a = [4, 4, 4, 4]
print a.count(4) == len(a)
```

returns

```
False
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `set` should work:

```
list1=[4,4,4,4]
list2=[4,4,3,4]
comparison= set(list1).intersection(list2)
if len(comparison) > 1:
    print("No Combo found")
    #or a whatever you require to be done here to show no combo
```

Answer (score 0):

What I gather from your question is that you want to check

- are all elements in my list the same
- if so, which value is in the list.

I think the most Pythonic solution would be to cast your list as a set, for example

```
if set(dice_rolls) == {4}:
    # roll logic
```